# priority queue implementation in C- changing chars to ints

Tags: c, pointers, priority-queue, function-call

I am currently working on a project that requires a priority queue in C. I am using the code from [Rosettacode.org](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Priority_queue#C).

I am attempting to modify the priority queue so that it takes an integer instead of a character. I tried changing all of the variable types but I am getting the following error.

> test.c:62:16: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int'
>         to parameter of type 'int *' [-Wint-conversion]

This works perfectly when its a char, but suddenly stops when its an int. Why is this happening? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int priority;
    int *data;
} node_t;

typedef struct {
    node_t *nodes;
    int len;
    int size;
} heap_t;

void push (heap_t *h, int priority, int *data) {
    if (h->len + 1 >= h->size) {
        h->size = h->size ? h->size * 2 : 4;
        h->nodes = (node_t *)realloc(h->nodes, h->size * sizeof (node_t));
    }
    int i = h->len + 1;
    int j = i / 2;
    while (i > 1 && h->nodes[j].priority > priority) {
        h->nodes[i] = h->nodes[j];
        i = j;
        j = j / 2;
    }
    h->nodes[i].priority = priority;
    h->nodes[i].data = data;
    h->len++;
}

int *pop (heap_t *h) {
    int i, j, k;
    if (!h->len) {
        return NULL;
    }
    int *data = h->nodes[1].data;
    h->nodes[1] = h->nodes[h->len];
    h->len--;
    i = 1;
    while (1) {
        k = i;
        j = 2 * i;
        if (j <= h->len && h->nodes[j].priority < h->nodes[k].priority) {
            k = j;
        }
        if (j + 1 <= h->len && h->nodes[j + 1].priority < h->nodes[k].priority) {
            k = j + 1;
        }
        if (k == i) {
            break;
        }
        h->nodes[i] = h->nodes[k];
        i = k;
    }
    h->nodes[i] = h->nodes[h->len + 1];
    return data;
}

int main () {
    heap_t *h = (heap_t *)calloc(1, sizeof (heap_t));
    push(h, 3, 3);
    push(h, 4, 4);
    push(h, 5, 5);
    push(h, 1, 1);
    push(h, 2, 2);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", pop(h));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, evidently you are trying to modify the queue so that its elements are integers instead of *string*s.  Rather than changing `char` to `int`, therefore, you should be changing `char *` to `int`.

Comment: `push (heap_t *h, int priority, int *data)` and `push(h, 3, 3);` --> Hmmm.  3 is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `push()` function signature, the third argument is of type `int *`, but you're sending an `int` while calling it. Pointer to integer conversion is an implementation specific behavior and is has high potential for causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As I see it, you don't need `data` to be a pointer, a simple `int` everywhere should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

So previously your function prototype was (presumably) `void push (heap_t *h, char priority, char *data)` so a single character string (`"c"` as opposed to `'c'`)  argument being passed as the third parameter could be cast into a `char *` and the compiler wouldn't complain.

However, now that you've switched everything to `int`, the compiler has something to say about it.

**Another note**: In particular, the compiler would be silent if you passed a single character string, eg `"c"`. `'c'` would give a similar error to what you have now.

It seems like you misunderstood the original code to be using characters as data when really it was using strings. You switched all the `char`s to `int`s and now you have `int *` where you should have `int`.

Comment: No, not exactly.  A `char` passed as the third argument to the original function would elicit exactly the same warning that the OP observes in his modified code.  He has misunderstood the nature of the original, and therefore not performed the correct conversion.

Comment: Yea, I think I edited that in at the bottom of my answer. You are absolutely right though. I fixed the part in the main paragraph now.